# Setting TD value from previous TD

Tags: javascript, html, css, struts2

I have a table that is filled in with values dependant on a previous page
those avlues are filled in with struts apparently

but I'm not very good with all that stuff so is there a simple was I can do something like this, either with HTML only or maybe a small javascript I can put in tha page?

```
<Table>
<TR>
<TH>ID</TH>
<TD><s:property value="groupID" /><TD> <--Number generated by the page with struts
</TR>
<TR>
<TH>ID Value</TH>
<TD>foobar</TD> <-- the text I want to add in dependant on the number from the previous TD
</TH>
</Table>
```

so, is there a simple way to go about doing this? HTML, CSS, JavaScript solution maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that exact HTML, a simple script like this will do it. But if you don't know JavaScript, you should really  learn it so that you understand what you're doing.

```
<body>
    <Table>
        <TR>
            <TH>ID</TH>
            <TD><s:property value="groupID" /><TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TH>ID Value</TH>
            <TD>foobar</TD>
        </TR>
    </Table>
       <!-- The script is here so it won't run until the TABLE has loaded -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

          // This is a map of the struts values to your values
        var valueMap = {
            "1": "foo",
            "2": "bar",
            "3": "baz"
        };
          // Browser compatibility. Older IE uses 'innerText' instead of 'textContent'
        var textContent = ('textContent' in document) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

          // Get all the TD elements on the page
        var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

          // Get the text content of the first TD (index 0)
        var text = tds[0][textContent];

          // Get the value from the map using the text we fetched above
        var value = valueMap[text];

          // Set the text content of the second TD (index 1) to the mapped value
        tds[1][textContent] = value;
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: well I know very little java, I'm trying to learn it but it's going slowly. so how does this work? if I add more TD tags will it break?

Comment: @FateAverie: Lesson 1 - JavaScript is not Java. ;-) As long as the `td` elements you need to target are the first two on the page, it won't break. I'll update with some code comments.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear what I wanted to do, what I originally have it the first TD witha value and the second is empty, and I want to fill the second Td dependant on the value of the first lie if the id is 3 then it would fill in foobar, but if the value is like 4 then it would fill in "temp" instead of foobar

Comment: @FateAverie: Where will the potential values come from? Can they be statically included in the script?

Comment: They will be static for the time being, once I get a grasp for the whole JavaScript and Java and everything else I'm working with I might made them dynamic but right now static values will be more than enough

Comment: ...I had a typo in `getElementsByTagName`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to place the value 'groupID' (set in the first tr's td) into the second row's td element, then the following jQuery will do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Scrape the XML out of the TD containing the xml
    var tdXml = $('table tr').eq(0).find('td').html();
    // Grab the value of the value attribute (groupID)
    var value = $(tdXml).attr('value');
    // Set this value in the second row's TD
    $('table tr').eq(1).find('td').text(value);
}​);​
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xnkdu/)